# How to get a mustek 1248 UB scanner working?

Tags: 11.10, printing, hp, scanner

I have a mustek 1248 UB scanner and Ubuntu would recognize it but not scan from it, simple scan would tell me that it is unable to connect to the scanner and `xsane` would tell me

```
failed to open device invalid argument gt68xx:libusb:002:007
```

I tried chmod but nothing happened.

Comment: scanimage -L gives me "device `gt68xx:libusb:004:017' is a Mustek ScanExpress 1248 UB flatbed scannerb"

Comment: The AU way is to open a new question for the printer (and make this one solely about the scanner) ;)

Comment: also check `dmesg` for error messages (probably something like `dmesg | grep usbfs`)

Comment: @AhmedNematallah Please ask a new question for the printer

Answer (score 4):

The scanning part seems to have been solved:

```
cd /usr/share/sane/gt68xx/
sudo wget http://www.meier-geinitz.de/sane/gt68xx-backend/firmware/SBSfw.usb
sudo chmod a+r *
```

There are multiple sources for this but they all seem to be [based on this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=154429).

The printer [should be supported](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_professional_p1102.html) out the box but multiple people seem to be having problems with this particular model. I suggest you file a bug on [the HPLIP site](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/support.html).

Edit: [Some people suggest](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1479670)  that downloading/installing [the latest version](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html) of hplip might help but those posts are quite old. The current Ubuntu-version of hplip should be more than new enough.

Comment: thanks a lot xsane worked but the scanner thing didn't move and all it gave me was a wrong image

Comment: Thanks now the scanner worked, what i did is copy the PS1Gfw.usb from the CD and then rename it to the file you made me download, put it in that folder and xsane worked, now it's just the printer

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to enable Mustek 1248 UB scanner on Ubuntu 12.10:

```
sudo apt-get install xsane
sudo mkdir /usr/share/sane/gt68xx/
cd /usr/share/sane/gt68xx/
sudo wget http://www.meier-geinitz.de/sane/gt68xx-backend/firmware/SBSfw.usb
sudo chmod a+r *
```

And that's it.